# ContentPage Control (mv) --> MasterPage Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to acces a control thats located in a content page (withing a content place holder, a multiview control to be more exactp) from the master page?

The situation is, i have a menu with buttons thats located in the master page.

Now in my content page i have 1 content place holder.
In which a multiview with several views is located.

If i press a  button in the menu (MasterPage) then it should open the proper view (with its controls) displayed in the content place holder area.

I have set the ActieveViewIndex=0 but i am getting all sorts of wierd behavour.
I have to do something with the ActiveViewIndex++ somewhere but nothing seems to work.

edit::

```
string a = Request.Querystring["one"]
string b = Request.QueryString["two"]
if ( a == "addOne") // where addone is a redirection to the content page from the master page button
{
   mvMultieView.SetActiveView(vView1);
}
else
if ( b == "addTwo")
{
    mvMultieView.SetActiveView(vView2);
}
```

Any suggestions?
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way my team and I accomplished this task (and I don't know that it's the best method, but it was effective) was to use query strings (as you had in your previous question it looks like). We established a standard QS variable called `iView` that would determine the name of the view in question (not necessarily the control name itself, but some keyword that the content control would respond to). Since all of our pages/controls have a page base class they inherit from, we put a method in the base class (in our case it was at the page level, but in yours a control level might work) that was responsible for getting the requested view. In the control we would have a mechanism (switch perhaps) that would set the activeView. In some cases we just used the actual ID of the control (since it was a mystery to be obfuscated) and avoided the switch altogether.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.com?iView=mySecondView

partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.WebControl
{
    // blah blah control stuff

    public string getRequestedView()
    {
        return (Request.QueryString["iView"]) ? Request.QueryString["iView"] : String.Empty;
    }
}

...

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    View myView = myMultiView.FindControl(this.getRequestedView());
    if(myView != null)
        this.MyView.SetActiveView(myView);
}
```

Comment: Ty for the reply. But i already have 3 strings that request.querystring --> the 3 diferent pages the views come on. But how do i link this into this one "iView" variable? Regards.

Comment: @Tonz - since only 1 page can be displayed per browser window, and only 1 view can be displayed per multiview, this iView variable becomes a global construct. What version of .Net are you using? I can mock up a quickie example project of what I'm talking about and post it.

Comment: Cheer Joel!, asp 4.0.  But whats really wierd only the first button works properly and my second one just displays blank area. Even after starting all the code from scratch.

Comment: @Tonz - I've posted a sample solution here: http://www.joeletherton.com/zips/MultiViewQueryString.zip . It's pretty raw, and it operates solely on Response.Redirect (since query string is the passing mechanism) and Hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that using find control

```
View myView = (View)this.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderFullMain").FindControl("PlaceHolderMain").FindControl("Mymultiview")
```

Answer (score 0):

have you done this change in the Master page or content page?
because i also got the same problem.

I have link buttons in my master page which i need to activate view controls in content page.
the content page is not the currently loaded page.

will this method help for my solution?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.